# JQuery: AppendTo in order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**THE BACKGROUND:**
I have a wordpress blog which will output its stories in time order as expected

I have a left column **.leftColumn** and a right column **.rightColumn**

Im having wordpress output all the stories into my .leftColumn

After the stories are all outputted, im then having jQuery examine the facebook like count of the stories and the ones which are above a threshold value will be moved into the .rightColumn

```
fi = curElement.closest('.thePost');
$(fi).appendTo(".rightColumn");
```

The movement from leftColumn to rightColumn is fine

**THE PROBLEM:**

The facebook like count query results come at slightly different times at random, so that the stories when moved into the right column are in random order.  I wanted to keep the order that wordpress outputted the stories at (time order).

A simple way to keep track of this is that i've assigned a numeric ID to each story, so that we know the general order.

```
<div class="thePost" id="story1"> blah blah </div>
<div class="thePost" id="story2"> blah blah </div>
<div class="thePost" id="story3"> blah blah </div>
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Is it possible to have the jQuery examine whats already in rightColumn and place the current element above or below it based on the storyX id to it keeps everything in order (using appendTo or any other way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a small plugin that checks the ID's and inserts the new element in the right order, it's not that hard.

Something like this would work

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.stickTo = function(elem) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var posts = $(elem).append(this).find('.thePost');

            posts.sort(function(a,b) {
                return a.id.replace(/\D/g,'') - b.id.replace(/\D/g,'');
            }).appendTo(elem);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function($) {

    curElement.closest('.thePost').stickTo(".rightColumn");

});
```

Comment: Wow, this thinking looks incredible, in practice it doesn't work for me for some reason.  Diagnosing it now.  By default my rightColumn is completely empty when the page first loads, could this have to do with why its not working for me?  I want to rule that out as a possibility before delving in deeper to diagnose my specific issue

Comment: Actually yes, this was the issue, with the rightColumn being empty to start with it wont kick off properly, I put a blank div with an id of 0 and then it all works wonderfully.  Is there a slight modification we can make so that this code will account for the empty start?

Comment: oooh, so close, so now it works without a blank starting div, but its no longer in proper order...

Comment: @Mark - changed the approach to something a bit simpler, just sorting the column. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically but you can use a setTimeout() to evaluate what is new in the column and append as you like.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

- Loop through your rightColumn stories using [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- Determine the story which you want to insert your new story after (by using [data-* attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) and retrieving the value using [`$.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/))
- Use [`$.insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) using the story in the step above.

Hope this helps!